# Jquery selector stops working when I'm trying to use id attribute instead of value

Tags: jquery

When I use value instead of id for example [value="' + this.value + '"] everything works fine but in this case, the selector is not working.

Sorry if that's a stupid question but I'm new to jquery and I can't find information related to my case at StackOverflow so I am posting here.

This is my code:

```js
var $select1 = $('#select1'),
  $select2 = $('#select2'),
  $select3 = $('#select3'),
  $select4 = $('#select4'),
  $select5 = $('#select5'),
  $select6 = $('#select6'),
  $select7 = $('#select7'),
  $options = $select2.find('option');
$options2 = $select3.find('option');
$options3 = $select4.find('option');
$options4 = $select5.find('option');
$options5 = $select6.find('option');
$options6 = $select7.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function() {
  $select2.html($options.filter('[id="' + this.id + '"]'));
  $select3.html($options2.filter('[id="' + this.id + '"]'));
  $select4.html($options3.filter('[id="' + this.id + '"]'));
  $select5.html($options4.filter('[id="' + this.id + '"]'));
  $select6.html($options5.filter('[id="' + this.id + '"]'));
  $select7.html($options6.filter('[id="' + this.id + '"]'));
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Select Service: *</label>
  <select class="form-select" size="3" id="select1" name="select1" required>
    <option value="softwaredevelopment" id="1">Software consulting</option>
    <option value="websites" id="2">Websites</option>
    <option value="qatesting" id="3">QA Testing</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select" id="select2" name="select2" required>
    <option value="consulting1-" id="1">Consulting 10</option>
    <option value="consulting20" id="1">Consulting 20</option>
    <option value="consulting30" id="1">Consulting 30</option>
    <option value="1-20pages" id="2">1-20 Pages</option>
    <option value="10-50pages" id="2">10-50 Pages</option>
    <option value="50-250pages" id="2">50-150 Pages</option>
    <option value="150-250pages" id="2">150-250 Pages</option>
    <option value="qa50" id="3">qa 50</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select" id="select3" name="select3" required>
    <option value="consulting510" id="1">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" id="1">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" id="1">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="nodesignneeded" id="2">No Design Needed</option>
    <option value="simpledesign" id="2">Simple Design</option>
    <option value="moderatelystylizeddesign" id="2">Moderately Stylized Design</option>
    <option value="highenddesign" id="2">High End Design</option>
    <option value="qa53210" id="3">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select" id="select4" name="select4" required>
    <option value="consulting510" id="1">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" id="1">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" id="1">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="notresponsivedesign" id="2">Not Responsive Design</option>
    <option value="responsivedesign" id="2">Responsive Design</option>
    <option value="qa53210" id="3">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select" id="select5" name="select5" required>
    <option value="consulting510" id="1">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" id="1">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" id="1">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="nodatabaseintegration" id="2">No Database Integration</option>
    <option value="basicdatabaseintegration" id="2">Basic Database Integration</option>
    <option value="advanceddatabaseintegration" id="2">Advanced Database Integration</option>
    <option value="fulldatabasedevelopment" id="2">Full Database Development</option>
    <option value="qa53210" id="3">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select" id="select6" name="select6" required>
    <option value="consulting510" id="1">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" id="1">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" id="1">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="noecommercefunctionality" id="2">No Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="basicecommercefunctionality" id="2">Basic Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="advancedecommercefunctionality" id="2">Advanced Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="enterpriseecommercefunctionality" id="2">Enterprise Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="qa53210" id="3">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select" id="select7" name="select7" required>
    <option value="consulting510" id="1">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" id="1">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" id="1">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="nocms" id="2">No CMS</option>
    <option value="basiccms" id="2">Basic CMS</option>
    <option value="advancedcms" id="2">Advanced CMS</option>
    <option value="enterprisecms" id="2">Enterprise CMS</option>
    <option value="qa53210" id="3">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ID can not be only number... [id="abc' + this.id + '"] it will work

Comment: I added letters in id attribute still not working, I also tried to do this [id="abc' + this.id + '"] still not working

Comment: @daremachine That's not true since HTML5.

Comment: `this.id` is the ID of the `<select>`. None of your options have IDs that are the same as the ID of the select (and IDs should be unique, so they can't have the same ID).

Comment: @Barmar but in case of 'this.value' selector works, and there is no value in select.

Comment: `this.value` refers to the property, not the attribute, and it holds the value of the currently selected option. Don't confuse attributes and properties! Consider learning Javascript and the DOM API and not some age-old library everyone is trying to get rid of.

Comment: @DoctorNasty if there is no `value` attribute the `.value` property will be the text content (`<option>`text content`</option>`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IDs are supposed to be unique, so you can't have the same `id="1"` in multiple options. Use a class instead of ID.

In the `change` event listener, `this` is the `<select>`, not the selected option. So `this.id` is the ID of the dropdown, not an option. Use `this.value`.

To make this fit together, the classes of the options in the other dropdowns should match the values in `select1`.

Instead of saving all the options in variables, you can just hide and show the options in each class. This allows you to use the same code for all the dropdowns, by giving them the same class.

```js
var $select1 = $('#select1');

$select1.on('change', function() {
  if (this.value) {
    $(".dependent-select option").hide();
    $(`.dependent-select option.${this.value}`).show();
  } else {
    $(".dependent-select option").show();
  }
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Select Service: *</label>
  <select class="form-select" size="3" id="select1" name="select1" required>
    <option value="softwaredevelopment">Software consulting</option>
    <option value="websites">Websites</option>
    <option value="qatesting">QA Testing</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select dependent-select" id="select2" name="select2" required>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="consulting1-" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 10</option>
    <option value="consulting20" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 20</option>
    <option value="consulting30" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 30</option>
    <option value="1-20pages" class="websites">1-20 Pages</option>
    <option value="10-50pages" class="websites">10-50 Pages</option>
    <option value="50-250pages" class="websites">50-150 Pages</option>
    <option value="150-250pages" class="websites">150-250 Pages</option>
    <option value="qa50" class="qatesting">qa 50</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select dependent-select" id="select3" name="select3" required>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="consulting510" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="nodesignneeded" class="websites">No Design Needed</option>
    <option value="simpledesign" class="websites">Simple Design</option>
    <option value="moderatelystylizeddesign" class="websites">Moderately Stylized Design</option>
    <option value="highenddesign" class="websites">High End Design</option>
    <option value="qa53210" class="qatesting">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select dependent-select" id="select4" name="select4" required>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="consulting510" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="notresponsivedesign" class="websites">Not Responsive Design</option>
    <option value="responsivedesign" class="websites">Responsive Design</option>
    <option value="qa53210" class="qatesting">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select dependent-select" id="select5" name="select5" required>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="consulting510" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="nodatabaseintegration" class="websites">No Database Integration</option>
    <option value="basicdatabaseintegration" class="websites">Basic Database Integration</option>
    <option value="advanceddatabaseintegration" class="websites">Advanced Database Integration</option>
    <option value="fulldatabasedevelopment" class="websites">Full Database Development</option>
    <option value="qa53210" class="qatesting">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select dependent-select" id="select6" name="select6" required>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="consulting510" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="noecommercefunctionality" class="websites">No Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="basicecommercefunctionality" class="websites">Basic Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="advancedecommercefunctionality" class="websites">Advanced Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="enterpriseecommercefunctionality" class="websites">Enterprise Ecommerce Functionality</option>
    <option value="qa53210" class="qatesting">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-select dependent-select" id="select7" name="select7" required>
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="consulting510" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 510</option>
    <option value="consulting2230" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 2230</option>
    <option value="consulting33420" class="softwaredevelopment">Consulting 33420</option>
    <option value="nocms" class="websites">No CMS</option>
    <option value="basiccms" class="websites">Basic CMS</option>
    <option value="advancedcms" class="websites">Advanced CMS</option>
    <option value="enterprisecms" class="websites">Enterprise CMS</option>
    <option value="qa53210" class="qatesting">qa 53210</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: With this code selector is not working on iphone, it shows load failed in console

Comment: What iOS version? Maybe it's an old version that doesn't support template literals, so change that to concatenation.

Comment: iOS 15.2.1, latest version. I tried all browsers same problem.

Comment: Can you get any more details about what the error is? It's hard to know what to fix with such a generic error.

Comment: I can't, I don't have a Mac to use Safari Web Inspector. I found some extension like Web Inspector in App Store and it only says load failed in the console.